# Capistrano: how to run a command-line rake task and rescue only for specific errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, capistrano, sunspot

In our Capistrano deploy, we have a task to make sure our Solr (via Sunspot gem) is running:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start"
```

However, this will throw an error if Solr is already running, killing the deploy, so we add `; true` to the end of the command so Capistrano will finish:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start; true"
```

There's two problems with this:

1. It will still continue running if a more serious error occurs, in which case we want the deploy to stop.
2. It prints out a long and ugly error trace.

I've tried putting this command in a `begin … rescue` block, then matching the message like so:

```
begin
  run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start"
rescue RuntimeError => failure
  if failure.message =~ /#{text_to_match}/
    logger.debug "Solr is already running: continuing"
  else
    raise failure
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the `message` on the error is just "failed: " followed by the command that failed, which doesn't allow me to distinguish between the benign error of the server already running and a possibly more malignant other error. It also still prints out the long and ugly error trace, so neither of my problems are solved.

**Is there a way to run a command-line rake task and rescue only for specific errors in Capistrano?** Ideally, I would also like to get rid of the long, ugly error trace, but that's of course a secondary concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have answer to your question, but you can ensure that command doesn't try to start solr already running.

```
run "cd #{current_path} && if [ ! -f #{solr_pid} ]; then RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start; fi
```

I assume that there is `solr.pid` (if solr runs as a deamon it should be there) and `solr_pid` is path to that pid.

Update: You can also use `ps aux` to check if solr process is really running:

```
if ! ps aux | grep -q "[s]olr production" ; then echo 'solr not running'; fi
```

I am using `[s]` in grep argument because otherwise `ps aux` command would catch itself. I am not sure what phrase would be proper to find solr process, so probably you will have to use something more precise.

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I want! I ended up replacing "run" with "capture" to prevent Capistrano from printing the entire ps aux command, then searched the captured string via regex to determine if Solr is running or not.